# What is the most efficient way to make money in Gran Turismo 5?

Tags: gran-turismo-5

What is the most efficient way of earning money in Gran Turismo 5, in terms of credits earned per time spent driving?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Some of the **Seasonal Events** added in the recent update (1.05) have very good prizes. So far I've only attempted the 493hp GT-R race but coming 3rd gave me 340,000.

This update has also increased the rewards for winning races, but this is only in effect until the end of January 2011.

See http://blog.eu.playstation.com/2010/12/20/gran-turismo-5-functionality-update/ for more details.

**Update:**

After the release of the [spec 2.0 patch](http://us.gran-turismo.com/us/products/gt5/spec2/), there is now a "Consecutive Login Bonus" - a bonus to both prize money and experience points. This bonus increases for every consecutive day you log into the game, up to a maximum of 5 days of increases.

The bonus is as follows:

- 1 day: 110%
- 2 days: 130%
- 3 days: 150%
- 4 days: 170%
- 5 days: 200% (ie. double rewards!)

So, make money *even more* efficiently by logging in each day for 5 consecutive days, then tackle some races.

Comment: These are, while very rewarding, not repeatable for more Cr.

Comment: Not repeatable, but it looks like new races will appear regularly, all with similar-sized rewards.

Comment: It's hard to beat races where you can earn 2,000,000 for 5 laps. And so far there's been 5 races per week (albeit with different rewards) so it's a steady source of income. I earned enough for the Formula GT in a little over an hour! Cairnz' answer is the best for a pure grind.

Answer (score 15):

A-Spec, Extreme series, American Championship, Indianapolis Motor Speedway.

Use a Race Modded Corvette (total cost ~600,000) for ~100k every 4-5 minutes. This seems to be the grind to go to for repeatable cash.

Comment: +1 for this, having now got access to this race, you can effectivly farm 97k every 5 minutes! So doing this race for 30 minutes would net you 587k, so manage to do it for an hour and you get 1m credits! Do the race 58 times and you can buy a GT by Citroen Race Car! ;)

Answer (score 6):

If you are just after money and don't mind "playing unconventionally" (i.e. cheating) there is something you can do. I have only read about this and have not tried it.

The basic idea is:

- Get yourself one of the Forumla One cars (e.g. the X2010)
- Choose a race on one of the indy tracks (Like the Wind, or Dream Car Championship)
- Using a rubber-band on the controller hold the right analog stick to full throttle
- Using a rubber-band hold the left analog stick to almost straight ahead but just slightly to the right
- Start the race

You should shoot off to the lead and then the car should follow the circut all the way around. You can win the race without having to do anything.

You could basically do that in B-spec anyways. The thing that makes this trick really worthwhile is this:

- Once the race has started plug in a USB keyboard
- Put something on the enter key so it is held down

Now when the race is over it will 'enter' through the credit/xp screens and restart the race. So you can leave this set up indefinitley and it will rake in money to the tune of ~$1million per hour, plus XP.

Comment: I used to do this on GT2 with the Pike's Peak Escudo! I think this in combination with cairnz's answer is best. Just leave it on overnight and hey presto!

Comment: Hmm ... I suspect this does not work if there are cats in your house. I can picture going to sleep with the car at Indy and waking up to find that I'm driving a kart in circles.

Answer (score 3):

I would say the best way to earn money quickly is the Special Events.  Some of them like the Jeff Gordon NASCAR Racing school can be pretty quick to go through, and they will get you a lot of Credits and Experience for each one you complete.  I just did the Intermediate one last night and got roughly $50k per event.

The downside is that once you have already achieved a gold medal on a special event you don't earn anything from that event anymore.  So you can only use this trick once, but it's a good one anyway.

Comment: Yes I also found the special events to be lucrative, but once I've finished them I want to know the fastest way to earn millions of credits so I can get the most expensive cars.

Answer (score 2):

My friend who plays GT5 swears by going to B-Spec mode if he gets bored and just make his AI teammate do races for him. Easiest way of earning creds **ever**.

You could do all of the Top Gear specials, they're *super* easy to do. ;)

Comment: B-Spec has much higher lap counts for lower payouts. Even endurance races are very poor in payouts. But for getting Cr. while doing nothing, it's perfect :)

Comment: True, this is great if you have cars left over for the races that you used. Set it to maintain pace and go make a cup of tea, read the net or have a shower etc ;p

Answer (score 2):

Buy a formula gt or red bull x1 and complete the Like the Wind race. You'll probably get at least $1,400,000 per hour!!

Answer (score 2):

Well right now the Seasonal Events has a Muscle Car Championship race, gives you 305,000 for first.  My best time is 4:09.  So that's about 3.7 mil every hour.  But gets kinda of tiring after a while.  I try to keep it interesting by buying every car that is eligible for that race and seeing which one's the fastest.  So far I've only tried two: '70 Challenger and '69 Vet.  The Vet is a few seconds faster with my tuning (but I'm not very good at tuning)

Answer (score 2):

There is a new event that came out about a week ago called "La Festa Cavallino". Basically buy a stock Ferrari 458 Italia, upgrade it as much as you can (including Racing Soft tires), adjust the transmission so the top speed is like 215 and do the "Circuit de la Sarthe 2009" race. The race is 1 lap long, takes about 3'50", and gains you 168,000 credits for a first place finish. You can repeat this race over and over if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

In A-Spec mode, at Rome in the European circuit, 5 laps with a 1:03 average lap time in a Veyron gives you 99k.

Comment: BTW - this is in extreme mode: european races: rome circuit

Answer (score 1):

I put together my own USB-device to babysit B-Spec Bob:

Now I simply start a B-Spec race and plug this device into the USB-Port, the B-Spec races are then on repeat mode until the device is unplugged.

Comment: That's interesting, but I'm not sure how helpful this is unless you also publish a tutorial of how you made it...

Answer (score 1):

1st best way of making money=american championship fully tuned and modded zr1 98,000 per race.

2nd:European championship 5-6 min race for an 82,000 profit for 1st place

3rd=the dream car championship takes longer than like the wind but more money 74,000

4th=like the wind 70,000 a race for 2 mins work a bit faster tha the dreamcar.

Answer (score 1):

I've not played with the extreme sereies but I have found the easiest money is for the Professional series, Lightweight British and the London course.  My lap times for the Race modded Lotus Elise are as low as 51.5  and with only 3 laps and a payout of $24,100  You can net just under 100k every 12 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I do the Rome circuit in the professional series I think European championship( I haven't played in a while) I have an Audi r10 tdi '06 and I can get a good lap of about 56 sec and the race is 5 laps. You get like 85000 per race so it's like 170000 every 10 minutes. It's decent if you're willing to put the time into racing the same thing over and over.

Comment: I don't know what series it's in

Comment: Ya know what, it might be worth more than that, all I know is that it's definitely over 85000 per race

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the new Tous France Championnat Seasonal Event has a race on the Sarthe Cicuit which will net you just over 100k for just over four minutes of driving, depending on your car.  I won a '99 Citroën Xsara Rally Car recently and it destroys in "stock" form.  All I added was a set of sports soft tires and went to work.  You could get a fully customizeable transmission and up the top speed a little bit and trim a few fractions of a seconds, if you're in a time crunch.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently an online only american muscle car challenge with the first track as daytona.  Nets you about 110k for 5 laps and your car only has to be able to top 175mph to win.  I added a few mods to a 69 corvette I found used and can blow around all 5 laps in 6:30 for 110k and still lap at least half the other cars.  I run those for an hour every other day or so when I want to go shopping :)

Answer (score 0):

For me personally, I pre-ordered from Amazon and got a code for a Mazda 787B race car. Then I just redo the Professional Series > Supercar Festival > Daytona.

This makes you 21k every 2mins. So it works out about 100k every 10 minutes, which is the best I've found so far. I'm rank 17 ish.

Comment: It's worth noting that with the new Remote Racing feature, you can make money without even needing to play.

Answer (score 0):

Im level 35 and use the Seasonal Events Sport Pickup Truck event (new) on the Mt. Aso track, gets you 90,100 for 5 laps at 1:05:00 a lap in a supped up Toyota Tacoma. Thats also about a million an hr. Im doing it to get every car, got 540 cars right now, half way there :)

Answer (score 0):

soup up an Audi A6 (the one in the dealerships before the quattro '09) and do the European champ. In extreme series

Mines over 900 hp and it's a money making machine

Answer (score -1):

I just raced the Honda Cup in the Special Events and won all 5 races for 300k each race!